# How to display back button when navigating to self with navigation component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have set up my navigation bar like this

```
with(ActivityHolderBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)) {
        setContentView(root)
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("holder") as NavHostFragment
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(fragment.navController,AppBarConfiguration(fragment.navController.graph))
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
```

But this only shows a back button when I navigate to another fragment and not when I navigate to self on the fragment marked as start destination.

Comment: Can you explain why you have multiple instances of your start destination on the back stack?

Comment: @ianhanniballake my first fragment shows a list with folders and files in it. If a user selects a folder I need to make an instance of the same fragment to show its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118997479):

> setupActionBarWithNavController uses the current destination ID to determine if the Up button is shown, so the behavior you're seeing is working as intended.
>
> You can have multiple destinations that use the same Fragment class, so just create a separate destination for recursive calls:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/catalog_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/categories">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:name="somepackage.categories.CategoryListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/catalog_category_list_frag">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_category_to_category"
            app:destination="@id/categoriesRecursive" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_category_to_product_list"
            app:destination="@id/products_frag" />

        <argument
            android:name="categoryId"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoriesRecursive"
        android:name="somepackage.categories.CategoryListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/catalog_category_list_frag">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_category_to_category"
            app:destination="@id/categoriesRecursive" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_category_to_product_list"
            app:destination="@id/products_frag" />

        <argument
            android:name="categoryId"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />

    </fragment>
    ....
</navigation>
```

So by having two different IDs, it is possible for `NavigationUI` to distinguish between your first level (which should not display an up arrow) vs ones that should display an up arrow.